# How to generate Request & Response templates from WSDL in python

Tags: python, soap

I am trying to generate a request and response template from a WSDL.

I know SOAP UI can do this, but I need to use Python in my case.

I have seen that there is a python lib called **zeep**, but it seems to be targeted more towards setting up a soap client and performing calls.

How can I get the request from the WSDL?

Here is an example I have been using:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_example.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can create the request XML documents with zeep, see http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/client.html#creating-the-raw-xml-documents

Comment: Is it possible to turn off the validation? Getting Validation error and I don't control the service and the endpoint.

 "Missing element %s" % (self.name), path=render_path)
zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element Header